# segmentation fault Crashing program in c, while implementing nested linke list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

So basically I have a function that takes information from a file and implements it unto a linked list, which is structured like this:

```
struct aluno{
    char nom[NAME_SIZE];
    char numest[NUM_SIZE];
    char curso[CURSO_SIZE];
    char ano[NUM_ANO];
    char regime[REGIME_SIZE];
    struct aluno *pnode;
};

struct exame{
    struct aluno *stds;
    char dsp[NAME_SIZE];
    char regi[REGIME_SIZE];
    char sala[REGIME_SIZE];
    char ano[NUM_ANO];
    char mes[NUM_ANO];
    char dia[NUM_ANO];
    char hora[NUM_ANO];
    char dur[NUM_ANO];
    struct exame *pnode;
};
```

While doing the so called nested linked list, whilst it seem to work fine, after leaving the while the program crashes. Here's the function:

```
while(strcmp(c,"inicio\n")!=0){
                tmpstd = malloc(sizeof(struct aluno));
                if(tmpstd == NULL){
                    printf("Memoria Nao Alocada");
                    exit(1);
                }
                fgets(c, sizeof(c), ex);
                token = strtok(c,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->nom,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->numest,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->curso,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->ano,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->regime,token);
                tmpstd->pnode = NULL;
                node->stds->pnode = tmpstd;
                node->stds = tmpstd;
                printf("gay\n");
            }
            printf("gay2");
```

The function stops the while correctly but crashes before printing "gay2".

For whom it may concern here's the rest of the entire function:

```
struct exame *exames(){
    FILE *ex = fopen("exame.txt","r");
    char c[NAME];
    struct exame *node,*tmp,*head;
    struct aluno *tmpstd;
    head = (struct exame *)malloc(sizeof(struct exame));
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Memoria nao alocada.");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        head->pnode = NULL;
        tmp = head;
        while(fgets(c, sizeof(c), ex)){
            node = malloc(sizeof(struct exame));
            if(node == NULL){
                printf("Memoria nao alocada.");
                exit(1);
            }
            char *token = strtok(c,";");
            strcpy(node->dsp,token);
            printf("%s",node->dsp);
            token = strtok(NULL,";");
            strcpy(node->regi,token);
            fgets(c, sizeof(c), ex);
            token = strtok(c,";");
            strcpy(node->dia,token);
            token = strtok(NULL,";");
            strcpy(node->mes,token);
            token = strtok(NULL,";");
            strcpy(node->ano,token);
            token = strtok(NULL,";");
            strcpy(node->hora,token);
            token = strtok(NULL,";");
            strcpy(node->dur,token);
            fgets(c, sizeof(c), ex);
            strcpy(node->sala,c);
            while(strcmp(c,"inicio\n")!=0){
                tmpstd = malloc(sizeof(struct aluno));
                if(tmpstd == NULL){
                    printf("Memoria Nao Alocada");
                    exit(1);
                }
                fgets(c, sizeof(c), ex);
                token = strtok(c,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->nom,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->numest,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->curso,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->ano,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,";");
                strcpy(node->stds->regime,token);
                printf("%s  %s  %s  %s  %s",node->stds->nom,node->stds->numest,node->stds->curso,node->stds->ano,node->stds->regime);
                tmpstd->pnode = NULL;
                node->stds->pnode = tmpstd;
                node->stds = tmpstd;
                printf("gay\n");
            }
            printf("gay2");
            node->pnode = NULL;
            tmp->pnode = node;
            tmp = node;
        }
    }
    fclose(ex);
    return head;
}
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: `strcpy(node->stds->nom,token);` : `node->stds` is uninitialized.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't quite understand.. Could you please elaborate, or perhaps tell more or less how it should be? Thanks!

Comment: You need allocate spaces pointed by `node->stds`.